# Detect the system language of a localized Windows XP installation

Tags: c++, windows, localization

I am trying to detect the system language of a localized Windows XP installation - I mean the language, which is used for the User interface, folder names and so on. For example I have a Russian version of Windows and the English text "My Computer" is "Мой компьютер".

I use the following API functions:

GetSystemDefaultLangID
GetSystemDefaultUILanguage

but they both return 1033 (or 0x0409 in hex), which means English.

In short - I want to find out which function(s) I should use in order to understand that the system language is Russian in a computer where "My Computer" is "Мой компьютер" :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try GetUserDefaultUILanguage it is available on Windows ME and later, GetSystemDefaultUILanguage is available on Vista and later.

Comment: You are wrong - GetSystemDefaultUILanguage is available on XP. Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318123(v=vs.85).aspx

Anyway, I tried also the function GetSystemDefaultUILanguage and it also returns the same result (English).

Comment: I stand corrected I was thinking GetSystemPreferedUILanguages. Anyways I just tried GetUserDefaultLangID and GetUserDefaultUILanguage on Windows 8 w/ MUI and get the right codes. I don't have a localized XP box at hand to try it but I have tried it before without problems. Maybe something wrong with your XP installation? Is it OEM? Do you have another box to try it on? Please post back when you figure it out. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. 
The installation of Windows is totally in Russian, but the language which is set in Control Panel is actually English. So, all these functions return "English". I don't know if this is a customized Windows installation, but if someone is interested I can provide Teamviewer access to my computer to check, because I give up now.

Comment: Note that GetUserDefaultLangID is not correct for determining the user's language - it returns the locale setting, not the system language, which is not what you want.